# mysql(): This function is deprecated in Typo3

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

I am moving one website to a newer server and this error is appearing on the front end.

```
PHP : mysql(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_query() instead in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/typo3conf/ext/ph_nextgenmenu/pi1/class.tx_phnextgenmenu_pi1.php line 93
```

I understand that there the function might be deprecated. The problem is that this is the third website I move to the new server, the previous two had the same Typo3 version 4.4.0 and all of them have the same line of code used to get to the database so it isn't a case of a deprecated function, is some misconfiguration that I can't find.

This is the code on that function:

```
function getPages($parentId)
    {
        $pages = array();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE doktype IN(1, 2, 3, 4) AND deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0 AND pid = " . $parentId . " AND nav_hide = 0 ORDER BY sorting ASC";
        $result = mysql(TYPO3_db, $query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $pages[] = $row;
        }
        return $pages;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to note, even a website that was made in Typo3 v4.7 last autumm has that mysql() function.

Comment: Did the other two websites had error_reporting on?

Comment: Maybe errors are turned on in your `php.ini` file for this site. Depending on how you're hosting your site(s), they may reference different initialization files. Errors may be turned off for the other sites but on for this one. Despite the fact that the other two sites did not report this error, the error is indeed correct. `mysql()` is deprecated along with all of the `mysql_*` functions. You should consider upgrading to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` functions.

Comment: The problem is while the other websites load perfectly this website only loads the error. Since they are on the same server and the account doesn't have custom configurations I guessed they'd share the same php.ini

Comment: display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On

in php.ini

Comment: Newer versions of TYPO3 no longer use `mysql()` and `mysql_*()`, but have migrated to `mysqli`. I think the update was done for TYPO3 6.2 (not sure), so an update would solve the problem. TYPO3 4.7 is almost 2.5 years old and has its end of life at the end of this month anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, have the other sites with this typo3 versions the same typo3 extension (ph_nextgenmenu) installed and using them?

After that please activate the error reporting on the other sites in the Typo3 INSTALL_TOOL. The part you have to look for is "display_errors". Maybe that the other sites have the same issue to.

At least, if the PHP Version is newer and not including the deprecated functions like the extension in the error message i recommend to upgrade to a newer typo3 version and find a way to replace the extension (ph_nextgenmenu) with a newer one or edit it manually to use the TYPO3 SQL API or the newer php functions directly.

if you want to change the extension Queries to the TYPO3 API maybe the API documentation helps you.

i think if you disable the extension in the extension manager the site should work like the other sites?

Comment: The site doesn't work if I disable the extension, basically the website is full of old deprecated functions. We told to the client to get a new website. Thanks